# Mysq no acepta dospuntos en un campo " : " en un campo error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, express, sintaxis

Estoy construyendo la consulta de los datos que me llegan del navegador para hacer la modificación en la base de datos :

```
consquery='UPDATE maquinas SET TECNICO= ' + req.body.TEC + " ,  MAC= "+ req.body.MAC +  ' WHERE maquina= ' + req.body.MQ +'';
```

y el resultado de la construcción del query es el siguiente:

```
UPDATE maquinas SET TECNICO= 8888,  MAC= 11:13:88:88 WHERE maquina= 20123423
```

Al enviar el Query a Mysql me da error 1064. si le quito todos los dos puntos " : " al valor de MAC es decir en ves de (11:13:88:88) pongo (11138888) asignado  MAC me funciona la modificación del registro pero si no me sale el error

> "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
> "errno": 1064,
> "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':13:88:88 WHERE maquina= 20123423' at line 1",
> "sqlState": "42000",

como puedo enviar el campo a guardar con los " : " en el valor de MAC?

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Las cadenas de texto van entrecomilladas: `'11:13:88:88'`.

Comment: Como puedo hacer esto si estoy construyendo el query con una variable que me llega del navegador ? si lo entrecomillo se me convertirá en un string y la variable MAC quedará como req.body.MAC

Comment: Concatena; algo como `+ "'" +`.

Comment: Eres un Genio!! muchas gracias ya me funciona!!

Comment: @jucarsal ya que lo has solucionado pon la solución a tu problema para posibles usuarios futuros con problemas similares

Comment: He modificado la construcción del Query de la siguiente forma: consquery='UPDATE maquinas SET TECNICO= ' + req.body.TEC + " ,  MAC= + "'" + req.body.MAC + "'" +  ' WHERE maquina= ' + req.body.MQ +'';  ya funciona el Query.

Comment: Muy bien @jucarsal pero eso explicalo en donde pone respuesta